# Question about Bitcoin rate

Tags: exchange-rate

1 or 2 months ago, 1BTC=120-130$. Today, 1BTC= 900$ at Bitstamp rate. Is that means if I bought BTC 2 months ago and I try to sell them today, I earn 780$ per BTC?

Comment: Seeing the vote to close for being off-topic (this question talks about current and recent market conditions), I am inclined to agree. Almost. Could it be edited to be about a general phenomenon in bitcoin, bursts of huge appreciation?

Comment: This question doesn't seem to be about the current value as much as about understanding how currencies can be exchanged one for another, and how to calculate profit of such transactions. The question is asking to confirm somebody's understanding of the concepts of *unit conversion* and the *rule of proportion*.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about elementary math, i.e. unit conversion and rule of proportion.

Answer (score 3):

The exchange rate has changed by almost 800 dollars. That means that *if* you *had* bought 1 bitcoin before the rise, you *would have* assumed the full risk of the price not rising (and possibly falling), and you *would have* been rewarded for taking this risk with a profit of almost 800 dollars. Note that you would be exposed to additional risks, including a possible bankruptcy of the bitcoin exchange you use, as nowadays even reiterated in mainstream media. See [this CNBC piece](http://www.cnbc.com/id/101270049) on today's warning to this effect by the European Banking Authority for example.